# An expression for teacher in charge of a class

Tags: expressions

In China, the teacher in charge of a class is called "Bang zhu ren", who not just teach, but also take care of students' life beyond study. So in English, what's the expression?

Comment: In the UK when I was teaching, 'form tutor' was the term I was familiar with.

Comment: You need to give more details; does _students' life beyond study_ include social aspects (welfare / leisure) or solely extra-curricular academic issues (such as appropriate courses, necessary qualifications)?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "Class" can mean the group of students in a single classroom for a single teaching session, or it can mean the body of students in the same year in the school.

Answer (score 5):

**Mentors** and **faculty advisors** are the terms used. Both of them can be in charge of a class or a group of students.

Faculty advisors are teachers whom you can approach in case of any difficulty like academic registration, help with choosing subjects and for obtaining permissions. You can find more information about their duties [here](https://www.rwu.edu/sites/default/files/expectationsadvisorsstudents_0.pdf).

A mentor maintains a **more personal** relationship. S/he is supposed to bond closely by going out on short trip and host dinners. Mentors act as a guide to choose your area of interest in your specialization, counsel you when needed and literally be your "on-campus parent".

Comment: Hello, Himabindu. This may be true and a good answer, but unless accompanied by supporting references where appropriate, an answer is not considered a good one on ELU.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you have downvoted the answer, I would like to know what I should do to improve it. I have already added references.

Comment: Your linked definitions of 'faculty adviser' and 'mentor' do not really license the pastoral ('life beyond study) component OP requires. You should add the supporting definitions to your answer rather than just link; this is spelled out at the Help Center.  And voting is a private matter (though I usually explain why I have downvoted where I have downvoted, which some appreciate): I haven't downvoted here FYO.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth There is no site which expounds the role of a mentor as much as my answer does. The sites only give a meaning that is synonymous to an advisor. I'm a university student with a mentor, I have first-hand experience of being a mentee. I have used my experience here  and it is not opinion-based. Some of the answers needn't be referenced every time as long we are cognizant of what we answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I will keep in mind about the links. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[class teacher](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/class-teacher)  (Macmillan)

> a teacher who teaches or is responsible for a particular group of students in a school